# remember the last state of the Bool variable

Tags: flutter

I’m doing a show. And I wanted to know how I saved the last status of my Bool variable so that when I leave the program and come back in it’s the same as when I leave, someone has some idea of how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't only apply to Flutter. I would look into storing in a database. But, Flutter is a UI framework. I'm not sure what your backend is, but this should handle data persistence, not the UI. However, there are [libraries](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite) which exist to do this. You can also look into [shared preferences](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/shared_preferences).

Comment: You can save it to text file or database and update when it changed.

Comment: use shared_preferences: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the app can be closed or killed by the system, so it surely needs some persistent storage usage. It can be on the phone or in the cloud. For your need the most simplest would be to use [Shared Preferences](http://%E2%80%9CShared%20Preferences%20%E2%80%94%20How%20to%20save%20Flutter%20application%20settings%20and%20user%20preferences%20for%20later%E2%80%A6%E2%80%9D%20by%20Didier%20Boelens%20https://link.medium.com/w1SMm5TzW6) library and keep your Boolean locally as a setting/configuration.